# Flask always listens default address and port

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to access my flask program on localhost from other devices like Android phone in my network.

I can access my localhost created using Apache but can not access program created by Flask.

This is my Flask program:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home_page():
    return '<h1>Welcome to my site!</h1>'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5050, debug=False)
```

When I run it, it always listens 127.0.0.1:5000.

```
 * Serving Flask app "server"
 * Forcing debug mode off
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

I can see my PHP files in localhost but cannot see Flask program. (i.e. http://my_ip:5000 doesn't work)

Answer (score 1):

Simply change '0.0.0.0' to your LAN IP address. You can know that typing `ifconfig` on `Linux` or `ipconfig` in `windows` in a *cmd* or a *terminal*

### For Example

```
app.run(host="192.168.1.41")
```

Comment: I gave static ip to my computer which is 192.168.1.15 and used it to access apache local host but using it in app.run() changes nothing. Still same.

Comment: If it boots up correctly then it should show " Listening to 192.168.1.15 " and then u can access the app at http://192.168.1.15:5000 ( if the port is 5000 which is the default that is)

Comment: Yes but flask app doesn't change that ip. Always it says "Listening to 127.0.0.1:5000" Impossible to  change that ip or port. That is the problem.

Comment: that's weird it is not the case for me here. do u restart the server? do you save your file? seems pretty dumb but I remember having a problem because of not saving my file.